# Identify Contracts in a list of evm addresses

Tags: ethers.js

I have a list of Ethereum addresses. I would like to determine which addresses are wallets & which are contracts.

I can run

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const addresses = [
"someAddress1",
"someAddress2",
"someAddress3",
];

addresses.forEach(address => {
  console.log(address, ethers.utils.isAddress(address));
});
```

to determine which addresses are valid **addresses**, but I need a way to dteremine which are **contracts**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution found [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1042#issuecomment-691715544)

and detailed below:

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const addresses = [
  "someAddress1",
  "someAddress2",
  "someAddress3",
];

const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();

addresses.forEach(address => {
  console.log(address, "is Contract: ", (await provider.getCode(address)) !== "0x");
});
```